# How do I import all functions from a package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a directory as such:

```
python_scripts/
     test.py
     simupy/
          __init__.py
          info.py
          blk.py
```

'blk.py' and 'info.py are modules that contains several functions, one of which is the function 'blk_func(para)'.

Within '__init__.py' I have included the following code:

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

file_lst = os.listdir(dir_path)
filename_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x[-3:]=='.py', file_lst))
filename_lst = list(map(lambda x: x[:-3], filename_lst))
filename_lst.remove('__init__')

__all__ = filename_lst.copy()
```

I would like to access the function 'blk_func(para)', as well as all other functions inside the package, within 'test.py'. Thus I import the package by putting the following line of code in 'test.py':

```
from simupy import*
```

However, inorder to use the function, I still have to do the following:

```
value = blk.blk_func(val_param)
```

How do I import the package simupy, such that I can directly access the function in 'test.py' by just calling the function name? i.e.

```
value = blk_func(val_para)
```

Comment: Please note that using wildcard imports in Python is discouraged by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for added a lot of confusion when debugging and because they might have side-effects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty easy

`__init__.py`:

```
from simupy.blk import *
from simupy.info import *
```

---

Btw, just my two cents but it looks like you want to import your package's functions in `__init__.py` but perform actions in `__main__.py`.

Like

`__init__.py`:

```
from simupy.blk import *
from simupy.info import *
```

`__main__.py`:

```
from simupy import *

# your code
dir_path = ....
```

---

It's the most pythonic way to do. After that you will be able to:

- Run your script as a proper Python module: `python -m simupy`
- Use your module as library: `import simupy; print(simupy.bar())`
- Import only a specific package / function: `from simupy.info import bar`.

*For me it's part of the beauty of Python..*

Comment: Is there a way to import the modules in __init_\_.py in a non-explicit fashion? Say I have many modules in the simupy package, and that it would be too troublesome to type "from simupy.module import *" for every module

Comment: There are, but I cannot tell you it's a good practice, lot of well designed libraries import all modules by hand, it's ok